# VSTS work items not showing in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops

I am using Visual Studio Team Services for a project. I created the project on the VSTS website (using the SCRUM template), and successfully added my source code to the project's source control in Visual Studio 2015 Community. I am able to check in source code, so that part is fine.

Then, on the VSTS website, I added some Backlog Items, and added some tasks to them. I then went back to Visual Studio, and went to Team Explorer, and looked in both the "My Work" and the "Work Items" sections, and my Backlog Items are not showing up, even after refreshing.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing nothing. What you are experiencing is expected. You need create a **New Query** under Work items section, then query PBI work items.

Also, check my reply in [this case](/questions/36851371/changing-task-to-in-progress-in-tfs-2015-kanban-board-does-not-reflect-in-visu), which explains why you not see work items in My Work section.